# Can the question filter be more helpful?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, quality-filter

I just asked a question.

Some sort of robot grammar check (the most horrifying of them all??!) pops up, tells me my post just cannot be posted as-is. Unreadable or something? I dunno.

Anyway, I have no idea what the problem is - is it my use of capital letters? My actual grammar in the question? The system is tight lipped - seems I don't have ways of making it talk.

Really irritating, can the system please be made to be more helpful (let us know what triggered the refusal to post!). Otherwise, this is just irritating.

I ended up cuttting & pasting a lot of text from a newspaper article. That confused the system enough to let me pass.

Really irritating, friendly solution needed!

Comment: What exactly were you trying to post?

Comment: If your are referring to this recent question [Where do i put image for appcelerator ios?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31502917) it doesn't look to bad. However, you should know by now (having been a user for more than 3 years that you shouldn't put "thanks" at the end of your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill well, i don't use SO as much as i used to, but you've found the question i asked. If it doesn't like thanks then it should say so. Not tell me "the grammar is bad".

Comment: I think the system is deliberately not described, to prevent people from circumventing it.

Comment: @S.L Barth But... isn't the point of the system to help fix things? If we had a compile error that was as vague, we would complain... surely a computer site can do at least as good as (typically terrible) compile errors?

Comment: Cleaned up your two most recent questions some. Though after 220+ questions you should know how to do it...

Comment: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176717) gives some (probably not all) of the rules ...

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post a bit. I believe the term "grammar nazi" is part of why it isn't received well. I hope this more neutral tone will cause it to be better received. (Rest assured, I can understand  the frustration when you need to resort to tricks just to get something posted!)

Comment: @bharal you realise passive aggression is just another form of rudeness, right? And *"good breeding"* is for livestock. Anyway, I've removed the comments; in the future, if you get someone to proof-read your questions, the original problem goes away too.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression. If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you."

Comment: "i find being polite is a mark of good manners". Yes, it assuredly is. And it's very bad manners to knowingly break the communities norms on what is good manners. Just doing it in ignorance can *sometimes* be excused, depending on the circumstances. See [the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176717) David gave for the whole discussion.

Comment: Voting to leave open. The underlying question is if the quality filter can't provide some feedback; which is a fair question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you have tripped the [quality-filter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/quality-filter/info); I've added the tag to your question.

The rules of the quality filter are deliberately not disclosed; otherwise people would just avoid these rules, when the purpose is to improve their question overall.

Your use of capitalization probably isn't the reason; I've seen -and fixed- plenty of posts that got the capitalization wrong.

What may have tripped it is if you Capitalized Every Word In A Sentence, or other things that people do that they believe makes them "cool".

It is indeed annoying that you don't get feedback from the system itself; you can go to Meta (like you did) or ask people around you to help formulating a question. You could also get help on the Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange chat.

The quality filter probably uses weighted values. I don't think grammatical mistakes count very heavy, because we have many users from non-English countries and it would be unfair -and counterproductive- to require they were all fluent in English.